# Oracle Update: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: vb.net, plsql

I have the following code in a VB .NET application.  I am trying to update columns in an Oracle table with data with SQL data.  When I run the application, I get (ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended) for the 'or_cmd_3.ExecuteNonQuery()' line.

If I strip out the code and run it in TOAD or SQL Developer, replacing the temp varialve with some bogus data it updates fine.  What am I missing?

Many thanks in advance.

```
  ElseIf (oracle_summary_temp = ueio_tmpALM_Summary) And (oracle_request_ID_temp = ueio_tmpALM_ID) And added_to_alm = "1" AndAlso ({"Deferred", "Rejected", "Closed"}.Contains(ueio_tmpALM_Status)) Then
Dim update_oracle As String = Nothing

update_oracle =
"update SCHEMA.TABLE set ISSUE_ADDED_TO_ALM = '2'," & _
"ISSUE_STATUS = '" & ueio_tmpALM_Status & "'," & _
"ISSUE_REJECTED_REASON = '" & ueio_tmpALM_Rejected & "'," & _
"ISSUE_PHASE = '" & ueio_tmpALM_Current_Phase & "'," & _
"ISSUE_PRIORITY = '" & ueio_tmpALM_Priority & "'," & _
"ISSUE_SYSTEM_IMPACTED = '" & ueio_tmpALM_System_Impacted & "'," & _
"ISSUE_DQ_ANALYST = '" & ueio_tmpALM_DQ_Analyst & "'," & _
"ISSUE_COMMENTS = '" & ueio_tmpALM_Comments & "'," & _
"ISSUE_OWNER_DEPARTMENT = '" & ueio_tmpALM_Owner_Department & "'," & _
"ALM_ISSUE_ID = '" & ueio_tmpALM_ID & "'," & _
"DQ_Team = '" & ueio_tmpALM_DQ_Team & "'" & _
"where ISSUE_SUMMARY = '" & ueio_tmpALM_Summary & "'"

Dim or_cmd= New NetOracle.OracleCommand(update_oracle, OracleConn)
or_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building a query text concatenating input strings is allways a bad practice.
One reason is that you need to remove characters that break the query like a single quote or other defined by your database query syntax.
But the most important reason is the possibility of [Sql Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
That said, the possible reason of your error is the missing space before the where clause.
You should replace all of your text using parameters in this way:

```
update_oracle = "update SCHEMA.TABLE set " & _
       "ISSUE_ADDED_TO_ALM = '2'," & _ 
       "ISSUE_STATUS = :tmpALMStatus, " & _
       "ISSUE_REJECTED_REASON = :tmpALMRejected," & _ 
       "ISSUE_PHASE = :tmpALMCurrent_Phase, " & _
       "ISSUE_PRIORITY = :tmpALMPriority," & _
       "ISSUE_SYSTEM_IMPACTED = :tmpALMSystemImpacted," & _ 
       "ISSUE_DQ_ANALYST = :tmpALMDQAnalyst, " & _ 
       "ISSUE_COMMENTS = :tmpALMComments," & _
       "ISSUE_OWNER_DEPARTMENT = :tmpALMOwnerDepartment, " & _ 
       "ALM_ISSUE_ID = :tmpALM_ID," & _ 
       "DQ_Team = :tmpALM_DQ_Team" & _
       " where ISSUE_SUMMARY = :tmpALM_Summary" 

   Dim or_cmd= New NetOracle.OracleCommand(update_oracle, OracleConn)   
   or_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":tmpALMStatus",ueio_tmpALM_Status)
   or_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":tmpALMRejected" ,ueio_tmpALM_Rejected )
   or_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":tmpALMCurrent_Phase",ueio_tmpALM_Current_Phase)
   or_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":tmpALMPriority",ueio_tmpALM_Priority)
   or_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":tmpALMSystemImpacted" ,ueio_tmpALM_System_Impacted)
   or_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":tmpALMDQAnalyst" ,ueio_tmpALM_DQ_Analyst)
   or_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":tmpALMComments",ueio_tmpALM_Comments)
   or_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":tmpALMOwnerDepartment",ueio_tmpALM_Owner_Department)
   or_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":tmpALM_ID",ueio_tmpALM_ID)
   or_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":tmpALM_DQ_Team",ueio_tmpALM_DQ_Team)
   or_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":tmpALM_Summary",ueio_tmpALM_Summary)
   or_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```